# UI Toolkit results "SendMessage cannot be called during Awake ..." warning

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried to use the UI Toolkit for my project, but constantly get these warnings (see screenshot) when I run the project.
I am loading my scenes using SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(), not sure if it matters.

This is my LoadScene method. I am not sure if this is related in any way, but decided to share it:

```
        public void LoadScene(string sceneName, bool displayLoadingScreen = true)
    {
        // TODO: Use Reflection to find Classes that implement IInitializer
        // When Loading a Scene, go through all IInitializer classes and check their IsDone and Progress properties ?

        if (displayLoadingScreen)
        {
            _loadingScreen.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }

        _loadingScenes.Clear();
        _loadingScenes.Add(UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(_currentScene));
        _loadingScenes.Add(UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Additive));

        StartCoroutine(GetSceneLoadingProgress(sceneName));
    }

    private IEnumerator GetSceneLoadingProgress(string sceneName)
    {
        foreach (var scene in _loadingScenes)
        {
            while (!scene.isDone)
            {
                yield return null;
            }
        }

        // yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

        _loadingScreen.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        _currentScene = sceneName;
    }
```

I searched the official forums before posting here, but cannot find working solution.
Any idea ?

I can add the whole SceneManager.cs file if you

[image]

Comment: By the way, just to add that I managed to reproduce the problem on completely new and empty projec.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of those messages (if there is any)

Comment: @derHugo there is no stack trace, but when you double click on the error the code leads to the EventSystem class from Unity.
I resolved my issue, you can check the answer that I wrote below. It is basically an issue with the EventSystem being loaded in separate scene from the one where the UI toolkit is used.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer for the question on reddit.
Basically the problem was caused, because I was adding my EventSystem in my initial 00_Loader scene ... and then I was trying to load another scene that uses the UI toolkit, but the second scene didn't had its own EventSystem. So I fixed it by moving the EventSystem to each individual scene, apart from the 00_Loader scene.

Here is a link to the post in reddit in case someone is interested.
https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/185c02g/ui_tookit_warning_sendmessage_cannot_be_called/

Comment: Great find! Could probably rather use [`DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) for this! Especially if you have a loader scene anyway. Then you don't need to copy the Eventsystem to all your scenes and maintain it in all places ... otherwise I hope you at least used a prefab ;)